# For Flex remote object calls (BlazeDS), is there a size limitation on objects returned?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, blazeds

I have a production mobile Flex app that uses RemoteObject calls for all data access, and it's working well, except for a new remote call I just added that only fails when running with a release build.  The same call works fine when running on the device (iPhone) using debug build.  When running with a release build, the result handler is never called (nor is the fault handler called).  Viewing the BlazeDS logs in debug mode, the call is received and send back with data.  I've narrowed it down to what seems to be a data size issue.

I have targeted one specific data call that returns in the String value a string length of 44kb, which fails (release build).  When I do not populate the String value (in server side Java code) on the object (just set it empty string), the result handler is called, and the object is returned, again, using the release build.  This works in a debug build.

The custom object being returned in the call is a very a simple object, with getters/setters for simple types boolean, int, String, and one org.23c.dom.Document type.  This same object type is used on other other RemoteObject calls (different data) and works fine (release and debug builds).  I originally was returning as a Document, but, just to make sure this wasn't the problem, changed the value to be returned to a String, just to rule out XML/Dom issues in serialization.

I don't understand 1) why the release build vs. debug build behavior is different for a RemoteObject call, 2) why the calls work in debug build when sending over a somewhat large (but, not unreasonable) amount of data in a String object, but not in release build.

I have't tried to find out exactly where the failure point in size is, but, not sure that's even relevant, since 44kb isn't an unreasonable size to expect.

By turning on the Debug mode in BlazeDS, I can see the object and it's attributes being serialized and everything looks good there.  The calls are received and processed appropriately in BlazeDS for both debug and release build testing.

Anyone have an idea on other things to try to debug/resolve this?

Platform testing is BlazeDS 4, Flashbuilder 4.7, Websphere 8 server, iPhone (iOS 7.1.2).  Tried using multiple Flex SDK's 4.12 to the latest 4.13, with no change in behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be a timing issue? Mayb the timeout settings on production server are more strict then on developement?

Comment: if you handle fault handler in the code, you can display what went wrong with the service. I'm too rooting on the timeout, i've displayed very huge remote objects before.. usually around 10k-30k rows etc.,

Comment: It's actually the same server.  This morning, after a week's worth of debugging, I found the issue.

The Java type returned from the call was defined as ArrayList.  Changing it to List resolved the problem.

I'm not sure why ArrayList isn't a valid return type, I've been looking at the Adobe docs, and still can't see why this isn't valid.  And, why it works in Debug mode and not in Release build is even stranger.  Maybe someone can shed some light on the logic here to me.

Answer (score 0):

After a week's worth of debugging, I found the issue.

The Java type returned from the call was defined as ArrayList.  Changing it to List resolved the problem.

I'm not sure why ArrayList isn't a valid return type, I've been looking at the Adobe docs, and still can't see why this isn't valid.  And, why it works in Debug mode and not in Release build is even stranger.  Maybe someone can shed some light on the logic here to me.